# Divide a list by elements of another list

Tags: python

I want to divide a list `error_variance_vector` by an element in another list `sigma_square1`, such that it gives corresponding `W` element (`w_i`).

```py
error_variance_vector=[]
for i in range(0,len(bpm_indexes)):
    n = 10
    error_variance_vector.append(n)

error_variance_vector = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10] 

sigma_square = [i**2 for i in error_variance_vector]
```

Here's my attempt:

```py
w = []
for sigma_square1 in sigma_square:
    w.append(error_variance_vector / sigma_square1)
    
W = np.diag(w)
print(W)
```

but I got an error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: Is `error_variance_vector` supposed to be a NumPy array?

Comment: Please also include your expected output. Do you want a matrix? Do you want a flattened vector? Do you want element-wise division?

Comment: @wjandrea i edited the post with the way i used to produce error_variance_vector

Comment: The right way to do this, especially if you're doing other analysis, is to use `numpy`.  With numpy, this would be one statement: `w = error_variance_vector / sigma_square`.

Comment: @Alexander Don't change the contents of error messages, and don't use quote formatting on them, since they're preformatted text. I fixed it for you.

Comment: @TimRoberts Could you explain more, do you mean i have to define the lists as numpy lists ?

Comment: By the way, you can simplify the loop that produces `error_variance_vector`, by just using a list comprehension: `error_variance_vector = [10 for _ in bpm_indexes]`. Or `error_variance_vector = [10] * bpm_indexes`

Comment: @ely66 That doesn't really answer my question. I'm saying, it looks like you want a vectorized operation, which Python lists don't support. If you simply convert the list to a NumPy array, then you can use vectorized operations on it.

Comment: @wjandrea It's better for SEO, where quotes are troublesome

Comment: @Alexander SEO? Why is that relevant?

Comment: @Alexander No no, I'm saying, you can't just change an error message. For debugging help, [it's important that we have the *exact* error message, not one that's been doctored](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). Either way, in my experience, Google mostly ignores punctuation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
w = [e/s for e,s in zip(error_variance_vector,sigma_square)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Zip the two together, then map over the results:

```
sigma_squared_vector = [i**2 for i in error_variance_vector]

w = [error / sigma_squared for error, sigma_squared in zip(error_variance_vector, sigma_squared_vector)]
```

If you don't need `sigma_squared_vector` for anything else, you can just inline its calculation, and reduce the two math operations to a single one:

```py
w = [1 / error for error in error_variance_vector]
```

Because `error / error ** 2` is effectively the same as `1 / error`.

Answer (score 1):

By the error you are trying to divide a list by an int.
Probably `error_variance_vector` is not a numpy array, but a standard python list. Convert it first (`numpy.array(lst)`) or create it as a numpy from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is because you're trying to divide an entire list by a single number. Python doesn't allow this with regular lists, but you can do it with numpy arrays. It's called [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and is one of the things that makes numpy powerful.

Since you're already using numpy, make use of its vectorization features. You don't need loops at all.

```py
import numpy as np

error_variance_vector = np.array([10] * len(bpm_indexes))
w = error_variance_vector / sigma_square
```

Comment: i want the error_variance_vector  to contain len(bpm_indixes) times a 10 number not a value that is multiplied by len(bpm_indixes) : this one works 
error_variance_vector = [10 for _ in bpm_indexes]

Comment: That is what `[10] * len(bpm_indexes)` does. It creates an array of size `len(bpm_indexes)` with the element `10`. It has the same result as `[10 for _ in bpm_indexes]` but looks nicer :)

Comment: Where's the division step? I'm not sure how this fits into OP's code.

Comment: Yes, sorry, typo. Edited.